# How to rename file based on parent and child folder name in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to rename file based on parent/subparent directories name.

For example: 
test.xml file located at

```
/usr/local/data/A/20180101
/usr/local/data/A/20180102
/usr/local/data/B/20180101
```

how to save test.xml file in /usr/local/data/output as

```
A_20180101_test.xml
A_20180102_test.xml
b_20180101_test.xml
```

tried shall script as below but does not help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

target_dir_path="/usr/local/data/output"

for file in /usr/local/data/*/*/test.xml; do
        l1="${file%%/*}"
        l2="${file#*/}"
        l2="${l2%%/*}"
        filename="${file##*/}"
        target_file_name="${l1}_${l2}_${filename}"
        echo cp "$file" "${target_dir_path}/${target_file_name}"
done
```

Anything i am doing wrong in this shall script?

Comment: `l1="${file%%/*}"` creates an empty string. Maybe you meant to strip the directory names *before* the directory name?  Perhaps `l1=${file#/usr/local/data/}"` or something like that? And *then* trim everything after the first slash.

Answer (score 2):

I've modified your code a little to get it to work. See comments in code

```
target_dir_path=""/usr/local/data/output"

for file in /usr/local/data/*/*/test.xml; do
    tmp=${file%/*/*/*}
    curr="${file#"$tmp/"}" # Extract wanted part of the filename
    mod=${curr//[\/]/_} # Replace forward slash with underscore
    mv "$file" "$target_dir_path$mod" # Move the file
done
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped and now script working fine. Just add / in mv command between $target_dir_path$mod. It should be like $target_dir_path/$mod. In case if anyone else refer your answer in future. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to do this operation:

```
source_folder="usr/local/data/";target_folder="target"; find  $source_folder -type f -name test.xml | awk -v targetF=$target_folder 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="_"}{printf $0" "; print targetF"/"$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' | xargs -n2 cp;
```

or on several lines for readibility:

```
source_folder="usr/local/data/";
target_folder="target"; 
find  $source_folder -type f -name test.xml |\
awk -v targetF=$target_folder 'BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="_"}{printf $0" "; print targetF"/"$(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF}' |\
xargs -n2 cp;
```

where

- `target_folder` is your target folder
- `source_folder` is your source folder
- the `find` command will search for all the `test.xml` named files present under this source folder
- then the `awk` command will receive the target folder as a variable to be able to use it, then in the `BEGIN` bloc you define the field separator and output field separator, then you just print the initial filename as well as the new one
- you use xargs to pass the result output grouped by 2 to the `cp` command and the trick is done

**TESTED**:

[image]

**TODO:**

you will just need to set up your `source_folder` and `target_folder` variables with what is on your environment and eventually put it in a script and you are good to go!

Comment: Nice solution :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have `perl` based `rename` command

```
$ for f in tst/*/*/test.xml; do
      rename -n 's|.*/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(test.xml)|./$1_$2_$3|' "$f"
  done
rename(tst/A/20180101/test.xml, ./A_20180101_test.xml)
rename(tst/A/20180102/test.xml, ./A_20180102_test.xml)
rename(tst/B/20180101/test.xml, ./B_20180101_test.xml)
```

- `-n` option is for dry run, remove it after testing
- change `tst` to `/usr/local/data` and `./` to `/usr/local/data/output/` for your usecase
- `.*/` to ignore file path
- `([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(test.xml)` capture required portions
- `$1_$2_$3` re-arrange as required